# csv column no filtering, no error

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, conditional-statements

File:

```
SYMBOL,DATE1,PREV_CLOSE,CLOSE_PRICE,DELIV_QTY,DELIV_PER,P/L_PER
20MICRONS,23-Feb-2017,36.55,35.9,41182,76.49,-1.77838577291
3IINFOTECH,23-Feb-2017,5.3,5.25,1240915,60.45,-0.943396226415
3MINDIA,23-Feb-2017,11135.85,11038.15,360,69.50,-0.877346587822
63MOONS,23-Feb-2017,80.3,80.6,26958,53.38,0.373599003736
63MOONS,23-Feb-2017,80.3,80.6,26958,53.38,0.373599003736
8KMILES,23-Feb-2017,588.75,586.75,10141,46.50,-0.339702760085
A2ZINFRA,23-Feb-2017,40.95,40.55,116344,48.67,-0.97680097680
```

As per my code and input file it should output all rows which have column `DELIV_QTY` is as per condition but when I run code, there is no error and no change in file.

please correct my code.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read csv('bhavcopy.csir', index_col = False) 
df[df.DELIV QTY >= 10000 ]
df.to csv('bhavcopy.csir', index = False)
```

Comment: small advice - [don't post images of code (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need assign output to `df`, because [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) doesnt work inplace:

```
df = df[df.DELIV_QTY >= 10000]
print (df)
       SYMBOL        DATE1  PREV_CLOSE  CLOSE_PRICE  DELIV_QTY  DELIV_PER  \
0   20MICRONS  23-Feb-2017       36.55        35.90      41182      76.49   
1  3IINFOTECH  23-Feb-2017        5.30         5.25    1240915      60.45   
3     63MOONS  23-Feb-2017       80.30        80.60      26958      53.38   
4     63MOONS  23-Feb-2017       80.30        80.60      26958      53.38   
5     8KMILES  23-Feb-2017      588.75       586.75      10141      46.50   
6    A2ZINFRA  23-Feb-2017       40.95        40.55     116344      48.67   

    P/L_PER  
0 -1.778386  
1 -0.943396  
3  0.373599  
4  0.373599  
5 -0.339703  
6 -0.976801
```

Another solution with [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df = df.query('DELIV_QTY >= 10000')
print (df)
       SYMBOL        DATE1  PREV_CLOSE  CLOSE_PRICE  DELIV_QTY  DELIV_PER  \
0   20MICRONS  23-Feb-2017       36.55        35.90      41182      76.49   
1  3IINFOTECH  23-Feb-2017        5.30         5.25    1240915      60.45   
3     63MOONS  23-Feb-2017       80.30        80.60      26958      53.38   
4     63MOONS  23-Feb-2017       80.30        80.60      26958      53.38   
5     8KMILES  23-Feb-2017      588.75       586.75      10141      46.50   
6    A2ZINFRA  23-Feb-2017       40.95        40.55     116344      48.67   

    P/L_PER  
0 -1.778386  
1 -0.943396  
3  0.373599  
4  0.373599  
5 -0.339703  
6 -0.976801
```

Comment: Hi jezrael, thank you for your quick comment and it's work.

Comment: Same is work for P/L_PER  but not work when i filter another column, if I search as string it's work. For ex, "100.00" in column "DELIV_PER". I put your command for >= 99 then no output but when i search for 'DELIV_PER == 100.00' then there is result. what have to do. there might  be datatype related issue. how can change all column value as float.

Comment: You can cast by `df['DELIV_PER'] = df['DELIV_PER'].astype(float)` and if dont work use `df['DELIV_PER'] = pd.to_numeric(df['DELIV_PER'], errors='coerce')` for convert non numeric values to `NaN`

Comment: Very thank you much!!!!!. I do same from stackoverflow. I replace non numeric value '-' to 0 (zero). very fast answer......very fast really.